# Why flask session didn't store the user info when making different posts to it from react?

Tags: python-3.x, session, web, flask, flask-restful

I wrote several APIs using Flask-RESTful and several react modules for testing purposes. Ideally, if I stored some info in session through a request, python should be able to detect whether there is such session even in other API entries with code, like

```py
if session:
    return jsonify({'user': session['username'], 'status': 2000})
return jsonify({'user': None, 'status': 3000})
```

However, the problem I met was within a single request, say login request, session was indeed properly used and `username` was also stored in the session —— for example,

```py
from flask import session
...

# login API

class UserLoginResource(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def post():
        ...
        ... # a user object (model) is defined
        session['username'] = user.username
        return jsonify({'status': 2000, 'user': session['username']})
```

with this code, it returned the exact username from session, which meant info was stored. However, when I made another get request from react side to the index API, like

```py
from flask import session
...

# index API (without any practical use)

class IndexResource(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        if session:
            return jsonify({'username': session['username']})
```

In this case, the response was None, cuz the API didn't detect any session.

```js
// makePostRequest Function

makePostRequest = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const payload = {
            'email': this.state.email,
            'password': this.state.password
        }

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {this.setState({
            status: res['status'],
            username: res['user']
        })})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

This is the way I make login post request. If login successful, it returns status code 2000; and if the status code is 2000, it means the program has gone through the code `session['username']=_the_username_`. And I should be able to extract username data from session storage when accessing Index page.

```js
componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => this.setState({
            user: res['user'],
            status: res['status']
        }))
    }
```

This is how I make a get request on the homepage module. However, the `user` is always *None* and `status` is always *3000*

This may be just improper use of session, but I don't know how to actually correctly use the session in flask. So, what was the mistake here?

---

Update:
So, I added a GET request within `class UserLoginResource(Resource)` like this

```py
class UserLoginResource(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def post():
        ... # identical to the previous code

    @staticmethod():
    def get():      # url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login
        session['username'] = 'user_a'
        return jsonify({'message': 'session set'})
```

And I made a get request in react side to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login` and got the `message: session set`. However, when react then accessed `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api`, the result remained to be `status` 3000 and None username. 
Then, I directly accessed the url `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login` and then accessed `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api` and there we go we had the username `user_a` and status `2000`.
So, I think the problem here might be that the backend didn't recognize the browser that was accessing it was the same person, or it might be others.
Also, I checked if it was something wrong with `componentDidMount`, but unfortunately `componentDidMount` wasn't the source of error — after I turned it into a normal function triggered by `onClick`, still it didn't work.
How to fix this?

Comment: what are you using to call the api? add that code to your question.

Comment: @waynetech yep. I just added the react code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` does not supports cookie by default, you need to enable it using `credentials: 'include'`

```
makePostRequest = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const payload = {
            'email': this.state.email,
            'password': this.state.password
        }

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {this.setState({
            status: res['status'],
            username: res['user']
        })})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Enable cors on server using `pip install flask-cors`

Then Add this to `app.py`, where you initialize your app

```
from flask_cors import CORS 
app = Flask(__name__) 
CORS(app)
```

Comment: for both get and post requests?

Comment: alright, console.log told me to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' to be true too in the header if `credentials: 'include'` was added, because of CORs

Comment: and to clarify, it's to set header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' to be true in response, which is the server side instead of the react side.

Comment: Check the answer, i have added the steps to enable cors